# In prediction, when should I use rolling windows vs. nonoverlapping ones?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, mathematical-statistics, forecasting, prediction

Suppose I have daily time series data and I want to predict a month in advance using a set of features. I have lots of them so I'll be using regularized linear regression. To create the response I can take nonoverlapping months or every day I can look forward a month. When is one appropriate vs. the other?

My goal is solely to make better predictions.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you test both strategy, and keep the best one ? Theoretically there should be no difference (what you win in variance is what you loose in degree of freedom). But that's theory.

May I suggest an other strategy: use cumulative data ($y_t = x_t + y_{t-1}$, instead of $x_t$). Again, it theory there is no difference, but in practice your data will show less variation and will look better on the graphs.

Comment: Can you please elaborate what you mean when you say "what you win in variance is what you loose in degree of freedom" ?

Comment: Quick answer: you cannot gain information from nothing. When you take a moving 30 day average, as opposed to group them by month, you do not add information. You simply look at the data differently, so the forecast will be the same. Maybe not exactly equal, because the standard deviation is not zero, but within the same interval of confidence. The long answer takes a bunch of algebra and a careful look at the n-p (called degree of freedom) that you use as denominator in the estimation of the standard deviation.